# Show there is a bijection between different definitions of Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

- **Definition.$1$**
  $$X\times_1 Y=\{ (x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}: x\in X, y\in Y\}$$
- **Definition.$2$**
  $$X\times_2 Y=\left\{ f\in Fonk\left( \left\{ 0,1\right\},X\cup Y\right)   : f(0)\in X, f(1)\in Y\right\}$$

Show there is a bijection between Definition $1$ of Cartesian Product and Definition $2$ of Cartesian Product.

My proof trying:
  Let $T$ be a function from $X\times_1 Y$ to $X\times_2 Y$. We will show that $T$ is bijection.

Case 1:
One-to-one. Let $a_1,a_2$ be any elements of domain of $T$. Then, $a_1$ of the form is $a_1:=(x_1,y_1)$, and $a_2$ of the form is $a_2:=(x_2,y_2)$. We need to show $T(a_1)=T(a_2)$.
**I couldn't continue my proof, can you help?**

Comment: I assume $Fonk(A,B)$ is the set of functoins $A\to B$ (more often written $B^A$)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes.

Comment: Edited definitions.

Comment: "Let $T$ be a function ... We will show that $T$ is a bijection" -- Taken literally, this cannot work. You better define a *specific* function $T$ instead of trying to show that any *arbitrary* function is a bijection

Comment: "Fonk" as functions?

Comment: @Ennar it could be anything with the property $(x,y)=(u,v)\iff x=u\land y=v$

Comment: @Hagen, yeah, I understood after I wrote it down that it's not really a clever question by me.

Comment: Send element $f$ of $X\times_2Y$ to element $(f(0),f(1))\in X\times_1Y$ and then prove that this is a bijection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define $$\begin{align}T\colon X\times_2 Y&\to  X\times_1 Y\\f&\mapsto(f(0),f(1))\end{align}$$
(because $f\in X\times_2 Y$ implies $f(0)\in X$ and $f(1)\in Y$ as required).

Showing that $T$ is injective and surjective is straightforward.
Alternatively, also define
$$\begin{align}U\colon X\times_1 Y&\to  X\times_2 Y\\(x,y)&\mapsto t\mapsto \begin{cases}x&t=0\\y&t=1\end{cases}\end{align}$$
and show that $U\circ T$ and $T\circ U$ are the identities on the two versions of product.

Comment: thanks for answer and comments